# WebView With Custom Navigation not coming in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview

I want to display a pdf in my Xamarin app. SO, I create a screen that contains a WebView. In that webView, I display my PDF. But the problem comes when I want to show the Custom Navigation too. The WebView does not show up instead I see just a white blank screen. This is my xcml:

```
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AAAIDApp.Views.CustomControls"
               xmlns:translate="clr-namespace:AAAIDApp.Extensions"
              x:Class="AAAIDApp.Views.pdfjsPage"   
             xmlns:renders="clr-namespace:AAAIDApp.Renders"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
            >
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid  Padding="0" Margin="0" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <local:CustomNavigation  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="CustomNavigationListPDF" CloseAction="CustomNavigation_CloseAction"   />

            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                <Grid IsVisible="False" Margin="20,10,20,10" ColumnSpacing="10" >
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label x:Name="TXTBck" Text="&#xf054;" FontSize="28" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" TextColor="{x:StaticResource IconBackColor}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">

                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Back_Tapped"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>


                    <Label x:Name="TXTIcons_Meeting" IsVisible="False" Text="&#xf073;" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}" FontSize="24" TextColor="{StaticResource FontTitleIconColor}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center" >

                    </Label>

                    <Label x:Name="TextTitle" TextColor="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="2"  VerticalOptions="Center" />

                </Grid>


                <!--<Grid>

                 <Label x:Name="Dowenload" Text="Download PDF" TextColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                 <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Download_PDF"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    </Grid>-->
               <Grid>
              <local:PdfWebView x:Name="PdfView" HeightRequets = "1000" WidthRequest= "1000" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ></local:PdfWebView>
                    </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

and my .cs file like this:

```
 public pdfjsPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CustomNavigationListPDF.PageTitle = "PDF";
            CustomNavigationListPDF.PageIcon = "\uf073";

       }
```

PdfWebView is empty:

```
{
    public class PdfWebView : WebView
    {
    }
}
```

CustomNavigation Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AAAIDApp.Views.CustomControls.CustomNavigation">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" >
            <Grid Padding="20,10,20,0" Margin="0" ColumnSpacing="10" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" Margin="0" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="30" >
                    <Label Text="&#xf053;" x:Name="LBLBack" FontSize="30" TextColor="#3d3d3d"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}">

                    </Label>
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BackLabel_Tapped"/>
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
                <!--<BoxView BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >

                </BoxView>-->

                <Label  x:Name="LBLIcon" TextColor="{StaticResource FontTitleIconColor}" FontSize="28"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" VerticalOptions="Center"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}">

                </Label>

                <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label x:Name="CustomNavTitle" VerticalOptions="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="{StaticResource LightGrayColor}" FontSize="Large"/>
                </StackLayout>


                <Frame BackgroundColor="Transparent" HasShadow="False"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Padding="0" Margin="0" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="30" >
                    <Label Text="&#xf00d;" FontSize="28" x:Name="btnClose" TextColor="#3d3d3d" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Center"  FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesome}">
                        <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Closed_Tapped"/>
                        </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Label>
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="BackLabel_Tapped"/>
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LineColor}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="1" Margin="0,5,0,0"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: First of all, please put the local:PdfWebView to a contentpage. If you can see this PDF show correctly, If this pdf could be showed, this issue is related to your custom navigation page.If not, please refer to this link or just use his code in your project.https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/showing-pdf-files-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Just writing this in contentPage works for me.<local:PdfWebView x:Name="PdfView" HeightRequest="1000"  WidthRequest= "1000" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" ></local:PdfWebView>
                    </Grid>

Comment: You can share your code of custom Navigation?

Comment: Shared the CustomNavigation File

Comment: I test your code in my project, delete the `Grid` of the `local:PdfWebView`, just put the `local:PdfWebView` in `stacklayout`, it could run normally.

Comment: It did, Thanks a lot

Comment: I post my comment to answer , and please mark it, it will help others who have similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete the `Grid` of the `local:PdfWebView`, just put the `local:PdfWebView` in `stacklayout`, it could run normally